# Adding space before \hline inside table with equations and between rows

Tags: tables, spacing, equations

I have a table with couple of equations and I'd like to add a small space between rows inside table and afer and before `\hline`. I already have the command `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}` inside the preamble but it does not affect the space inside the table I want to modify. Would you know a solution to this? Red arrows indicate where I'd like to have some spacing. Thank you.[image: table]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document} 

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Table}
\label{Tab:table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l | ll}
  \hline
  \hline
  First-order pole & $\frac{1}{\pi R_\text{load}C_\text{out}}$ & \SI{100}{\hertz}\\
  Second-order pole & $\frac{f_\text{sw}}{\pi}{\big(\frac{1}{D(1+\frac{V_\text{in}}{NV_\text{out}})}\big)}^2$ & \SI{100}{\hertz} \\
  Left half-plane zero & $\frac{1}{2\pi R_\text{ESR}C_\text{out}}$ & \SI{100}{\hertz}\\
  Right half-plane zero & $\frac{R_\text{load}}{2\pi \frac{V_\text{out}}{NV_\text{in}}\big(1+ \frac{NV_\text{out}}{V_\text{in}}\big)L_p}$ & \SI{100}{\hertz}\\
  DC gain & $\frac{V_\text{in}}{D_\text{iv}}\sqrt{\frac{R_\text{load}f_\text{sw}}{2L_p}}\frac{1}{S_e+S_n}$ & \SI{100}{\hertz}\\
  Duty cycle & $\frac{V_\text{out}}{V_\text{in}}\sqrt{\frac{2L_pf_\text{sw}}{R_\text{load}}}$  &\SI{100}{\hertz}  \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\\[the_additional_space_you_want]` instead of `\\` between two lines. For example, `\\[2mm]` will add 2 mm of additional vertical space between the two lines.

Edit: and to insert more space between the two first rules and the first line, you can insert a "strut" (a rule of width 0 and of the height you desire) between `\hline\hline` and the beginning of the line: for example `\rule{0mm}{5mm}` (first argument is the width, here 0, second is the height).

Answer (score 3):

for more vertical space in cells package `makecell` provide macro `\makegapedcells`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\caption{Table}
\label{Tab:table}
\makegapedcells
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l | >{$\displaystyle}l<{$} >{\SI{100}{\hertz}}l}
  \Xhline{1pt}
\makecell[l]{First-order pole}
    &   \frac{1}{\pi R_\mathrm{load}C_\mathrm{out}}                         &   \\
Second-order pole
    &   \frac{f_\mathrm{sw}}{\pi}{
        \left(\frac{1}{D\left(1+
                \mfrac{V_\mathrm{in}}{NV_\mathrm{out}}\right)}\right)}^2    &   \\
Left half-plane zero
    &   \frac{1}{2\pi R_\mathrm{ESR}C_\mathrm{out}}                         &   \\
Right half-plane zero
    &   \frac{R_\mathrm{load}}{2\pi\mfrac{V_\mathrm{out}}{NV_\mathrm{in}}
        \left(1+ \mfrac{NV_\mathrm{out}}{V_\mathrm{in}}\right)L_p}          &   \\
DC gain
    &   \frac{V_\mathrm{in}}{D_\mathrm{iv}}
        \sqrt{\frac{R_\mathrm{load}f_\mathrm{sw}}{2L_p}}\frac{1}{S_e+S_n}   &   \\
Duty cycle
    &   \frac{V_\mathrm{out}}{V_\mathrm{in}}
        \sqrt{\frac{2L_pf_\mathrm{sw}}{R_\mathrm{load}}}                    &   \\
  \Xhline{1pt}
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**edit:**

as pointed [Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908/bernard) in his comment, use of `\makegapedcell` has some issues (specific to this table); first cell in the first column is not left aligned. as cure for this mismatch in this cell i use `\makecel[l]{...}`.

beside this table looks is improved by with use of `\displaystyle`, `nccmath` package (both stolen from Bernard answer), `caption` package and `Xhline` from `makecell` package. also typing of units is shortened.

Comment: You have the same problem as I had, with `\makegapedcells`: the first row is indented, and I don't understand why…

Comment: @Bernard, now i see ... before i didn't notice this and i'm preaty sure, that in other tables, where i use `\makegapedcells`, this not happen. i know, that it doesnt work in all circumstances (for example with `m` columns). i will investigate this later.

Comment: It's also the first time I notice it, and it is for this particular table.

Answer (score 3):

A solution with `cellspace`, `booktabs`, `caption` for a decent spacing between caption and table, and a few other packages:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float, caption, booktabs, cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{6pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{6pt}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Table}
\label{Tab:table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l |>{$\displaystyle}Cl<{$}l}
 \toprule
 \midrule 
 First-order pole & \frac{1}{\pi R_\text{load}C_\text{out}} & \SI{100}{\hertz}\\
  Second-order pole & \frac{f_\text{sw}}{\pi}{\frac{1}{\Bigl(D\Bigl(1+\mfrac{V_\text{in}}{NV_\text{out}}\Bigr)\Bigr)^2} }& \SI{100}{\hertz} \\
  Left half-plane zero & \frac{1}{2\pi R_\text{ESR}C_\text{out}} & \SI{100}{\hertz}\\
  Right half-plane zero & \frac{R_\text{load}}{2\pi \mfrac{V_\text{out}}{NV_\text{in}}\Bigl(1+ \mfrac{NV_\text{out}}{V_\text{in}}\Bigr)^{\mathstrut}L_p} & \SI{100}{\hertz}\\
  DC gain & \frac{V_\text{in}}{D_\text{iv}}\sqrt{\frac{R_\text{load}f_\text{sw}}{2L_p}}\frac{1}{S_e+S_n} & \SI{100}{\hertz}\\
  Duty cycle & \frac{V_\text{out}}{V_\text{in}}\sqrt{\frac{2L_pf_\text{sw}}{R_\text{load}}} &\SI{100}{\hertz} \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: add `\displaystyle` is good idea ... i'm curious, where you use  `cellspace`?

Comment: @Zarko: Actually, it was there for a first trial  which didn't work, as itseemed incompatible with the `>{$}l<{$}`, so I changed for `\setcellgapes` (with some complications for the first row)… until I found your message and remembered  the pre-specifier had to be `C`, not `S`, due to `siunitx` loading. So, thanks for your comment! I returned to the initial version, which is simpler.